# How to visualize multiple bar plots using plt.subplots ,axis must iterate over all visuals, according to its index?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-visualization

i'm trying to plot life expectancy year by year for every country, i wrote a code which is working fine,

```
#Lets Create a Function that will create a relation between Year,life Expectancy with respect to different country



def EDA_features(country,life_expectancy,data):
    for i in set(data[country]):
        plt.bar(range(len(set(data[country]))),data[data[country]==i][life_expectancy])
        plt.xticks(range(len(set(data.Year))),labels=list(set(data.Year)))
        plt.xlabel('Year')
        plt.ylabel(f'{life_expectancy}')
        plt.title(f"Year vs {life_expectancy} for  {i}")
        plt.show()
```

i want to visualize this visualization in 3 or 2 rows using plt.subplots

i tried this code

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2, ax3), (ax4, ax5, ax6)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(10,5))
for ax,country in zip(list(set(df.Country)),[ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4,ax5,ax6]):
    sns.barplot(range(len(set(df.Year))),df[df.Country==country]['Life expectancy at birth (years)'],ax=ax)
    ax.set_xticks(range(len(set(data.Year))))
    ax.set_xticklabels(list(set(data.Year)))
    plt.xlabel('Year')
    plt.ylabel('Life expectancy at birth (years)')
    plt.title(f"Year vs Life expectancy at birth (years) for  {country}")
    plt.show()
```

its throwing this error AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all'

can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You have your zip in wrong order:

figures are on the second position, while countries are in the first one. Note that when you create the `ax,country` tuple at the beginning of the for statement the ax will contain the country and country will contain the subplot.

```
for ax,country in zip(list(set(df.Country)),[ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4,ax5,ax6]):
```

Swap this around like this:

```
for country, ax in zip(list(set(df.Country)),[ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4,ax5,ax6]):
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your data frame looks like this:

```
df =  pd.DataFrame({'Country':np.repeat(["A","B","C","D","E","F"],5),
                   'Life expectancy at birth (years)':np.random.uniform(50,80,30),
                   'Year':np.tile([2000,2001,2002,2003,2004],6)})
```

You can simply use [catplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html#seaborn.catplot), specifying the number of columns using `col_wrap`:

```
sns.catplot(x="Year",y="Life expectancy at birth (years)",
        col="Country",col_wrap=3,data=df,kind="bar",height=3)
```

[image]

Or simplifying your subplot code above should give a similar result:

```
fig,axs = plt.subplots(2,3, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(10,5))
axs = axs.flatten()
Years = df.Year.unique()
Countries = df.Country.unique()

for i,cty in enumerate(Countries):
    sns.barplot(x = "Year", y = "Life expectancy at birth (years)",
                data = df[df.Country==cty],ax=axs[i])
    axs[i].set_xticks(range(len(Years)))
    axs[i].set_xticklabels(Years)
    plt.xlabel('Year')
    plt.ylabel('Life expectancy at birth (years)')
```